# React: How to get submit button and text label to communicate with each other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, submit, form-submit

I have a small form with a subset of it looking like this:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
      <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        initialValues={{ datasetName: 'dataset.csv', contactEmail: 'johndoe@example.com', uploadFile: 'sample.csv' }}
        validate={validate}
        render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>


          ...

              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={submitting}
                >
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography name='subscribeMessage' variant='caption'>You have subscribed!</Typography>
              </Grid>

            </Grid>
          </form>
        )}
      />
```

I also have an onSubmit function, but I only want the text/label "You have subscribed!" to appear after the button has been clicked. How can I make this text appear only after the user clicks the submit button?

For reference, my submit function looks like this:

```
const onSubmit = async values => {
    console.log('Submitting subscribe form!');
    console.log('Subscribe form values:', values);
}
```

I am currently only working on the front end of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an internal state to check the submission and display the submission text according to it.

```
const [formSubmitted, setFormSubmitted] = useState(false)
```

And set it to true after a successful submission

```
const onSubmit = async values => {
    console.log('Submitting subscribe form!');
    console.log('Subscribe form values:', values);
    setFormSubmitted(true)
}
```

Then render the submitted message if *formSubmitted* is true

```
{formSubmitted  && <Grid item xs={12}>
   <Typography name='subscribeMessage' variant='caption'>You have subscribed!</Typography>
 </Grid>}
```